# Need help getting google domain to connect to my AWS ip address/ portfolio site

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53, portfolio

I have been trying everything possible to get my portfolio up so I can apply to jobs, and nothing is working. I created an elastic ip in ec2 for my instance and connected it, and added name servers and set up route 53. I have googled and tried every step and had my instructors try to help me but nothing works, and right when I think I finally did it right I'm stuck waiting the full 2 days for it to process just to be let down again. It has now been over 2 weeks and I am about to give up. I cannot transfer my domain to AWS either because it has not been 60 days. Does Google just not support AWS? Does anyone know how to make this work?
More details:
-I set up 4 custom name servers connected to my elastic ip, also a cname and a records
-the elastic ip works correctly
-i have tried enabling and disabling the DNSSEC settings
-custom resource records have an a record pointed to the ip and cname to the domain

*still need help with this issue, again nothing has worked*

Comment: You have not provided enough information for us to diagnose your problem. Please edit your question to provide more details. For example, does the EC2 instance work correctly when accessed via the Elastic IP address? Have you created a `CNAME` record in Route 53 to point to the instance? When you resolve the domain (eg with PING), does it return the Elastic IP address? What are the results of running `nslookup` on the domain?

Comment: I will do that thank you! And yes, my EC2 instance works perfectly via the elastic. I created the a and cname records and pointed them correctly. I did not use nslookup but i used a similar site and it said there were no errors. Google chat support also said that everything was okay on my end it must be an AWS issue, but I have talked to multiple and don't think they know much

Comment: Oops! I made a mistake. It should be an `A`-record, not a `CNAME`-record.

Comment: It might just be caching. Try it from a different browser, or preferably from a different computer on a different network (eg via your phone).

Comment: my a record points to my elastic ip and my www cname to my domain

Comment: I have been looking up my domain on both my phone and laptop every day the past 2 weeks to see if it has connected :/ it is makennamartin.dev

Comment: I have tried literally everything I am on the verge of giving up but I need it up so I can get a job, the domain is on my resume which is on my portfolio site

Comment: For me, that URL resolves to 3.129.153.7, which is an Amazon IP address. Is that the Elastic IP address associated with your instance? See: https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/3.129.153.7  According to the [list of AWS IP address ranges](https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json) that address is part of the `3.128.0.0/15` CIDR that has a service of `AMAZON` (but not EC2). I looked at one of my Elastic IP addresses and it is listed as a service of `EC2`, so something does not seem right.

Comment: The simplest and quickest method would be to remove the Custom Name Servers configuration from Google, and simply create an A-Record there to point to the Elastic IP address.

Comment: Yes that is it! I had everything connected and waited 2 days, then made the stupid decision to restore my name servers today because it recommended it for some reason. I reentered everything to the way it was before but it may take up to 2 days again for it to process but i know it will not work again

Comment: My a record and cname records have been the same the past 2 weeks tho. Do you think i should remove the cname record?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to point a domain name (managed on Google) to an Amazon EC2 instance with an Elastic IP address, then **the simplest method is to add a `A` record in your Google domain** that points to the IP address.

This does not require the use of Amazon Route 53, and it will work instantly.

However, if you wish to do *all* management of the domain within Route 53, then you will need to:

- "Use Custom Name Servers" on the Google domain
- Enter the four Name Servers shown in the Amazon Route 53 hosted zone
- On Amazon Route 53, create a `A` record that points the domain to the Elastic IP address

See: [How To: Connecting Google Domains to Amazon S3 | by Michelle | Medium](https://medium.com/@limichelle21/connecting-google-domains-to-amazon-s3-d0d9da467650)

Comment: I have tried both ways, and have waited 2 days each time to see if they worked. My instructors said I did everything correctly, and my ip address works. Do you have any ideas as to why it just will not work?

Comment: Oops! I made a mistake... It is an `A`-record, not a `CNAME`-record.

Comment: I have not used amazon s3 before, my instance is on ec2

Comment: Oops! True, that article is talking about S3. However, at the very bottom is shows how to point Google name servers to Route 53.

Comment: I have the 4 name servers set up perfectly from route53, however now I am considering learning about s3 buckets since mine doesnt have a backend, maybe that will finally work for me

Comment: Yeah think I need to give up on this for a week I am going insane